# I can't delete an AWS certificate because it is associated with a CloudFront distribution but the CF distribution no longer exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

I am trying to delete an AWS cert. In the ACM dashboard it states that is is still associated to a CloudFront distribution - therefore it will not let me delete it. The CloudFront distribution it states that it is associated with has been deleted for days and no longer exists.

I did a search and the only thing I have found so for is AWS telling me to delete a custom domain name for an API Gateway that might have been generated for this CF distro. I never set one up and if I look in the API gateway dashboard there are not even any API gateways there.

Any help on getting this cert deleted or disassociated with the non existent CF distribution?